# SQL removing duplicates in a certain column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Good afternoon all!

Had a question regarding the removal of duplicates in one column and making it remove the whole row. I will provide an example in a screenshot in Excel as to not provide proprietary info.

[image]

I am looking to remove one of the rows highlighted in yellow for example but do not want to limit it to one Dr.Mike or one Health Partners clinic for example. Relatively new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to remove all of the matching rows, or all-but-one? `delete` will delete all rows matching the criteria given in the `where` clause.

Comment: I'm sorry I also want to note there can be multiple providers at the same address and clinic as well

Comment: Would like to only remove the row that is duplicated on the address

Comment: This is for TSQL I am not in a position to delete rows out of the table itself strictly for reporting purposes

Comment: so you just want to `select`, not `delete`. so just use `select distinct`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used the below script to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT Prov, Clinic,Address, count(*)
  FROM SomeTable
  group by Prov, Clinic,Address
  having count(*)>1



  SELECT Prov, Clinic,Address, countrows = count(*)
INTO [holdkey]
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY Prov, Clinic,Address
HAVING count(*) > 1



  SELECT DISTINCT sometable.*
INTO holdingtable
FROM sometable, holdkey
WHERE sometable.Prov = holdkey.Prov
AND sometable.Clinic = holdkey.Clinic
AND sometable.Address = holdkey.Address

SELECT Prov, Clinic,Address, count(*)
  FROM holdingtable
  group by Prov, Clinic,Address
  having count(*)>1

DELETE sometable
FROM sometable, holdkey
WHERE sometable.Prov = holdkey.Prov
AND sometable.Clinic = holdkey.Clinic
AND sometable.Address = holdkey.Address

INSERT sometable SELECT * FROM holdingtable
```

Comment: OP said they cannot delete the data, just modify how it is viewed. Anyway, this is extremely overwrought for such a simple operation (assuming it is simple; it's hard to tell exactly what OP wants).

Comment: Apologies. I had drafted the answer before looking at the extra bit of information in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select distinct prov, clinic, address
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Comment: If this answered your question, then please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, please edit your question to clarify exactly what you want, as it's currently not completely clear.